# How do I apply the correct physics to a chain?

Tags: mesh, objects, physics

So I made these chains and a chain holder on the back of a truck but when I try to apply physics, every single ring glitches out going in random directions (sometimes blender just crashes). I just want to attach the chains to their top rings (the 7 top rings + the holder theyre attached too is 1 object). I already searched for a solution but they keep glitching, would be nice if someone could help me!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer, the margin is automatically set to .01m. This is too big for the little chains I made and made them explode all over the place. I put it to .001m and now it works like it should.